# Get all View objects onRestoreInstaceState

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("time",startTime);
        Log.i("myTest","onSaveInstanceState");
    }

private String TAG = "myTest";
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle viewHierarchy = savedInstanceState.getBundle("android:viewHierarchyState");

        if (viewHierarchy != null) {
            SparseArray views = viewHierarchy.getSparseParcelableArray("android:views");
            if (views != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "key -->" + views.get(i));
                    Log.v(TAG, "value --> " + views.valueAt(i));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "no view data");
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "Inside of onRestoreInstanceState");
    }
```

I was trying to restore Views on an orientation change and came through this article

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/

But sadly the method mentioned above returns set of null key values. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

The article which I have provided says that current view is saved when onSaveInstanceState() callback occurs

Comment: Can you make sure, that the corresponding view has an id attached to it?

Comment: Edit your post to include the code for `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: @MorrisonChang edited..

Answer (score 0):

Android standard views have their own mechanism of saving their state. They use [View#onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) and [View#onRestoreInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29)

For this to work views must have an ID set through XML `android:id` or `View#setID()`, that ID has to be more than 0.

Unless you have custom views (your own classes that extend any Android view) you don't need to handle this yourself.

However, Activity's onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState can be used in case you need to store special values to survive a configuration change.

Comment: I have given ID's. XML only contains a TextView and a Button. There ID's are textView1 and button1

Comment: And your views lost their text when the app rotates?

Comment: Log.v(TAG, "key -->" + views.get(i)); gives null

Comment: You don't need any code at all, remove those two methods and try rotation